# KTable/KStream memory consumption over time

Tags: memory, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

Is there a way to calculate how much heap (or any other) memory approximately will be used by KTable/KStream in java/scala application over time?

I have some specific assumptions and I'd like to know whether they are correct:

- Kafka streams use internal topics and RocksDB only.
- RocksDB is embeddable DB, so it uses heap memory of my application.
- KStream constantly deletes all records from RocksDB after they can no longer be used by any of processors in topology (e.g for join with specified JoinWindow) (== not so much memory used)
- KTable is fully stored in RocksDB (== in memory)
- When KTable receive null-value record it deletes record from RocksDB (== memory freed up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to estimate. For general sizing, consider this guide: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html

> Kafka streams use internal topics and RocksDB only.

Yes. You can also replace RocksDB with in-memory stores (that are part of Kafka Streams) or implement your own custom stores.

> RocksDB is embeddable DB, so it uses heap memory of my application.

RocksDB use off-heap memory and also spills to disk.

> KStream constantly deletes all records from RocksDB after they can no longer be used by any of processors in topology (e.g for join with specified JoinWindow) (== not so much memory used)

It depends on the store type. For key-value stores (ie, "regular" `KTable`s) data is not deleted (with the exception of explicit delete messages, so-call tombstones). For time-windowed/session-windowed KTables (result of windowed-aggregations) and joins, there is a retention period after which data is deleted.

> KTable is fully stored in RocksDB (== in memory)

RocksDB also spills do disk. It's not in-memory only.

> When KTable receive null-key record it deletes record from RocksDB (== memory freed up)

`null`-key records are not malformed. I assume you mean `null`-value record, so-called tombstone. Those are treated as deletes.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I mean null-value record.